# data.frame and splitting rows... not found a suitable solution for my data

Tags: r, dataframe

I am struggling a bit with my tables. I am trying to split some variables (using R), but I am having difficulties with one specific column.

My dataset is like this:

```
test<-data.frame(
 Chrom_no=c(1,1,2,3),
 Region=c('12..13','22..23','100','34..36'),
 Ref=c('AT','CG','A','AAA'),
 Alt=c('TA','GA','T','CGG'),
 Prob=c(99,98.7,99,99.9))
```

I want to separate all the regions that are grouped together. So far, I have solved for all the columns, but the 'Region' one:

```
ref2 <- strsplit(as.character(test$Ref), '')
alt2<-strsplit(as.character(test$Alt), '')

test2<-data.frame(
 Chrom_no=rep(test$Chrom_no, vapply(ref2, FUN=length, FUN.VALUE=integer(1))),
 Region=rep(test$Region, vapply(ref2, FUN=length, FUN.VALUE=integer(1))),
 Ref=unlist(ref2),
 Alt=unlist(alt2),
 Prob=rep(test$Prob, vapply(ref2, FUN=length, FUN.VALUE=integer(1))))
```

I don't know how to solve fix that column: e.g. '12..13': 12 should go on the Ref=A and 13 should go in Ref=T (first and second character, respectively). Things get complicated, as some of the columns have 3 characters (and corresponding range: 22..24), some will have more.

How could I solve? I have been looking for a solution in the last couple of days, but I am still not sure how to solve. I apologize if this has already been solved somewhere else.
P.S.: I am aware that in order to strsplit on the 'Region' column I need to use:

```
'\\..'
```

as separator.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your end goal correctly, you can look into using the "data.table" package. With it, you can set up your problem like the following:

```
library(data.table)
## Change your data.frame to a data.table
DT <- as.data.table(test)
## Convert the relevant columns to be characters instead of factors
DT[, c("Region", "Ref", "Alt") := lapply(.SD, as.character), 
   .SDcols = c("Region", "Ref", "Alt")]
DT[, list(Chrom_no = rep(Chrom_no, nchar(Ref)),          # Expand the Chrom_no
          Region = unlist(lapply(                        # Split Region and use
            strsplit(Region, "..", TRUE),                # the result to create
            function(x) {                                # the range of values
              x <- as.numeric(x)                         # needed
              if (length(x) > 1) seq(x[1], x[2]) else x
            })), 
          Ref = unlist(strsplit(Ref, "")),               # Split Ref
          Alt = unlist(strsplit(Alt, "")),               # Split Alt
          Prob = rep(Prob, nchar(Ref)))]                 # Expand Prob
#    Chrom_no Region Ref Alt Prob
# 1:        1     12   A   T 99.0
# 2:        1     13   T   A 99.0
# 3:        1     22   C   G 98.7
# 4:        1     23   G   A 98.7
# 5:        2    100   A   T 99.0
# 6:        3     34   A   C 99.9
# 7:        3     35   A   G 99.9
# 8:        3     36   A   G 99.9
```

The above code can probably be streamlined a bit, but I thought this should be enough to get you started.